# How to make you own insert page template in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word

Everyday i have to fill up a form, and have been quite annoyed on how i have been doing things. The form is appended to the file to accumulate for about a month before creating a new file for the next month. I am annoyed that for everyday i have to:

Insert Blank page -> Copy last page -> Paste on newly created page -> delete old data -> fill up with new data

I find the steps of Copy last page up to deleting data unnecessary steps. Would it be possible to have a templated page, and whenever needed i can just insert this empty templated page?

Answer (score 0):

### Create an AutoText or Building Blocks entry with your format

1. Follow your current procedure up through the point you delete the old data.
2. Format the first paragraph with the paragraph formatting of "page
   break before." *Perhaps that first paragraph is in a heading style
   where you can add that to the style.*
3. Select this page and use it to create your AutoText/Building Blocks Entry. The keyboard shortcut to do this is **Alt+F3** *(Fn+Alt+F3 on some computers)*.
4. Give your entry a name like _MyForm so that it will be unique.
5. Note which template you save it in and the name.

You can then recreate that any time by typing the name and pressing the F3 key. If it is saved in the Normal template it may be that you can insert it using the Enter key in response to a prompt.

Here is my writing on [AutoText](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete) and Building Blocks.

You may want to use **Content Controls** as placeholders for your data. Here is [Greg Maxey's page on Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html). Here is my page on [Creating Forms using Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/forms.htm).

*By the way, in Word jargon, "template" is a term of art describing a particular kind of Word file. Here is [my writing on Templates](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm).*

Comment: If you are using a Mac, the keyboard shortcut uses the Opt ky with the F3 key instead of the Alt key.